# A problem with 'manage.py migrate' it gives me an error

Tags: django, django-models, migration, database-migration

I made a variable 'user' in the class 'Service' in '`models.py`' which is a foreign key of another class 
then I gave it an attribute 'default='None'' .. I run '`manage.py makemigrations`' then '`manage.py migrate`' but it gave me the error like this:

```
packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 965, in get_prep_value
    return int(value)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'None'
```

.. so I deleted the variable 'user' but it still gave me the same error!
I tried to show migrations and it is like this:

- services

  ```
  [X] 0001_initial
  [X] 0002_auto_20190126_1417
  [X] 0003_auto_20190126_1423
  [X] 0004_auto_20190126_1425
  [X] 0005_auto_20190126_1436
  [X] 0006_auto_20190127_1434
  [X] 0007_auto_20190128_0915
  [X] 0008_service_user
  [ ] 0009_auto_20190130_1855
  [ ] 0010_auto_20190130_1856
  [ ] 0011_auto_20190130_1926
  [ ] 0012_auto_20190130_1928
  [ ] 0013_service_user
  [ ] 0014_remove_service_user
  [ ] 0015_service_publisher
  ```

I tried to delete the variable and make another one called it 'publisher' gave it attribute 'null=True' but it didn't work

```
models.py
    from django.db import models
    from django.urls import reverse_lazy, reverse
    from firstapp.models import User_Model

    class Category(models.Model):
        categoryName = models.CharField(max_length=150, primary_key=True)
        def __str__(self):
            return self.categoryName

    class Service(models.Model):
        serviceTitle = models.CharField(max_length=100, primary_key=True)
        deadlineDate = models.DateField(null=True, help_text='please Enter the 
    date in the format : year-month-day')
        price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=3, null=True, 
    default=10.00)
        serviceDescription = models.CharField(max_length=600, null=True, 
    default='Descripe your service')
        category = models.ForeignKey(Category, related_name='categories', 
    on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False, default='Engineering')
        publisher = models.ForeignKey(User_Model, on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
    null=True)
        def __str__(self):
            return self.serviceTitle

        def get_absolute_url(self):
            return reverse('serviceDetails', kwargs={'pk':self.pk})
```

Comment: you need to delete the migrations files. keep till 0013 then try again

Comment: I am still new to this 
so what is the command to delete them? @Exprator

Comment: manually delete them from the migrations folder of that app

Comment: Thanx alot it worked :D @Exprator